# How to solve scrolling size for MSchart controls graph c#

Tags: scroll, zooming, mschart

I made a graph using MSChart and I was able to implement the zooming ability.

The graph can zoom but the problem arises when I want to move around after I zoom. When I click up and down on the y axis scrollbar, the scrolling increment is fine. However, for the x axis scrollbar, the scrolling increment is horrible. It will always go the very end even though there is data in the middle.

I tried looking online for the solution but was out of luck

here is my code:

```
        // Chart area (where the axes and series are plotted)
        ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
        chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.MinValue.ToOADate();
        chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        chartArea.AxisY.Maximum = 100;
        //chartArea.AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
        chartArea.AxisX.Title = "Time";
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = DEFAULT_TIME_FORMAT_STRING;
        chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#########################";
        chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
        chartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
        chartArea.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        m_chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

        //add zoom-in features for x and y axis             
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.Interval = 0;
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;

        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.Interval = 0;
        //m_chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
        //m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
        m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
```

I dont see what I am doing wrong

Comment: I want to clarify the behavior of the scrolling for the x axis. When the data is mostly on the left hand side of the graph, and when I click the right button on the scrollbar, it will go to the very end of the graph and you cant see the middle of the graph (this is after zooming).

Comment: SO I figured it out.

Since the chart is sparce it will move to only significant data areas...unless u change the smallScrollSize.

So what I did was this  

    m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSize = (m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum - m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum)/60;

Answer (score 1):

Set the scaleview type to the appropriate time selection.

```
m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SizeType = "Seconds";
m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSizeType= "Seconds";
m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType= "Seconds";
m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType= "Seconds";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
m_chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
```

then the scroll bar will comes outside the chartarea and you will not face that problem.